# Redirect to facebook app after login from auth dialog

Tags: facebook, authentication, dialog

I got some problem with my testing app

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, publish_stream'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

This is the code I use to send user who has not logged in yet to login
via facebook auth dialog.
The problem is after login using facebook auth dialog
user will be redirected to my site which is not in facebook app.

How can I send user back to facebook app after login using auth dialog ?

Please help

Comment: The redirect sent by facebook is to the URL you've defined as your app's.  Define it correctly and you're good.

Comment: should I change this line ?
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, publish_stream'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

Comment: I have try to run the example Social cafe , its also redirect to developer's page after login , anyway to recdirect to facebook app page ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `redirect_uri` parameter of [getLoginUrl()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) to tell facebook where you want to send the user after authorization ends (let it be success or failure).

There's a number of restrictions on what you can use there, basically you got three options:

1. URL under your application's domain.
2. The canvas path of the application (if it has one): `https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE`
3. Any page url that has your application installed: `https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_USERNAME/app_YOUR_APP_ID`

By default, the php sdk takes the current url as `redirect_uri`. The documentation about these are under the [oauth dialog's documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) of the same parameter.

Comment: I try this https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_USERNAME/app_YOUR_APP_ID but it give me an error, Do i need to configure something in App setting ?

Comment: Need to have page tab callbacks in place ofcourse, but the documentation doesn't mention anything else. I guess having the app istalled on the page in question is needed as well. The second and third option is relatively new on facebook, could be a bug?

Comment: I have installed on my page's tab, Have you ever try something like this ?

Comment: The last time i did something like this, facebook only allowed `rediredct_uri` back to the app's domain. So i had a fb_redrop.php file that redirected the user once more time to the final location.

Comment: It look seem no solution right now, then I now use https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE instead better than redirect to my domain.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Was google-ing about the same issue and found a solution,so thought might as well answer her.

simply add the following code in the main page.

```
$config['appBaseUrl'] = "http://apps.facebook.com/your_app_name/";

if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
     header("location:" . $config['appBaseUrl']);
     exit;
}
```

$config is the array that i pass while creating the facebook object. In this context,its not necessary to create an array though.